# How do I find the quotient of the division of $x^{1993}+x^2+1$ by $x^2+x+1$?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, factoring

I have an exercise where I need to find the quotient of the division of polynomial $f=x^{1993}+x^2+1$ by $g=x^2+x+1$. I know to do it the long way but I think there is a trick to do it fast. By the way, I know the remainder is $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1$ you have $x^3\equiv 1 \bmod x^2+x+1$ whence $x^{1993}\equiv x$ and then it is trivial.

---

To expand: $f=X^{1993}+X^2+1=(X^{1993}-X)+(X^2+X+1)$

The first of these factors is $$X(X^{1992}-1)=X(X^3-1)(X^{1989}+X^{1986}+\dots +X^3+1)=$$$$=(X^2+X+1)(X^2-X)(X^{1989}+X^{1986}+\dots +X^3+1)$$ and dividing through by $(X^2+X+1)$ and multiplying through by $(X^2-X)$ gives a sum of pairs of terms of the form $X^{3n+2}-X^{3n+1}$ starting $X^{1991}-X^{1990}+X^{1988}-X^{1987}+\dots$

Comment: I know how to show that the remainder is 0 but I need to find the quotient.

Comment: @OvyOvy I have shown how to use this, but left you to finish off and add the extra $1$ at the end.

Comment: Seems fine, but how can I know that $X^{1992}-1=(X^3-1)(X^{1989}+\dots +X^3+1)$?

Comment: @OvyOvy That is a standard fact about $x^r-1$ dividing $x^{kr}-1$ and is derived, for example, by taking $y=x^r$ in $(y-1)(y^{k-1}+y^{k-1}+\dots +y+1)=y^k-1$. Here $r=3$.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote $$X^{1993}+X^2+1=X^{1993}-X+X^2+X+1=X\left(X^{1992}-1\right)+X^2+X+1.$$

Since $$X^{1992}-1=(X^3-1)(X^{1989}+...+X^3+1)=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)(X^{1989}+...X^3+1),$$
we see that $X^{1993}+X^2+1$ is divisible by $X^2+X+1$.

The  quotient it's $$X(X-1)(X^{1989}+...X^3+1)+1.$$

Comment: Sorry but what do I do after I write it like that?

Comment: It gives that $X^{1993}+X^2+1$ is divisible by $X^2+X+1$ because $1992$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I know how to show that it is divisible but I need to find the quotient.

Comment: ...and multiplying out gives the final desired answer of $$X^{1991}-X^4+X^2-X+1$$

Comment: Seems fine, but how can I know that $X^{1992}-1=(X^3-1)(X^{1989}+\dots +X^3+1)$?

Comment: Because $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1).$ Just expend it. After this put $x=X^3$ and $n=664.$